# Rust: dynamically building escaped unicode scalar values

Tags: rust, unicode

I want to create an escaped unicode scalar value at runtime. How can I achieve this?

```
let omega = "3A9";
assert_eq!("\u{3A9}", format!("\\u{{{}}}", omega))
```

Error:
*thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
left: `"Ω"`,
right: `"\\u{3A9}"`'*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to interpret the string as an hexadecimal integer and construct a `char` using it.

```rust
let omega = "3A9";
let code_point = u32::from_str_radix(omega, 16).unwrap();
let s = char::from_u32(code_point).unwrap().to_string();
```

Comment: Worth noting, if you control the source of the `omega` variable, it would be better to store it as a `u32` from the beginning: `let omega = 0x3A9`